# Argparser for boolen type

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

I am trying to pass arguments of type bool and while running the code I run `python main.py --tcpip=False`. This does not work for me.

I have tried to change it to type `str` and it works completely fine.

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="SSD and Gender Detection")
parser.add_argument("--tcpip",default = "True",type=str,help='transfer data via tcp/ip')
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args.tcpip)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    if(args.tcpip == "True"):
        send_data(count)
```

It prints `True` even when I start the code with 
`python main.py --tcpip=False`

Comment: `"True"` has type `str`.  `True` has type `bool`.  Just because a quoted string happens to consist of the word T-r-u-e doesn't suddenly cause the type to change from `str` to `bool`.

Comment: Yeah, this case is really unintuitive

Comment: `type=bool` fails because: `bool("False")` produces `True`.  The only string that produces `False` is the empty one, `""`.  Your `=="True"` is the right test.

Answer (score 3):

You should use the `action` argument:

```py
    parser.add_argument("--tcpip",action='store_false',help='transfer data via tcp/ip')
```

Now the value of `tcpip` is True by default, and when run with the argument `--tcpip`, the value will change to False.

```py
>>> python main.py
True
>>> python main.py --tcpip
False
```

Then you can change the condition to:

```py
if args.tcpip:
    send_data(count)
```

Some more reading - [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#action)

Comment: Also, a name like `--no-transfer` would make more sense.

Comment: completely agree @chepner just wanted to flow with the original example...

Comment: Yeah, I was going to add the comment to the question, but decided to put it closer to your correct answer.